# Contact Deletion

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contact-deletion

How could i proceed in order to delete all Contacts with Contact Deletion (about 17 million contacts)?
Using random data extensions I would have limits related to the number of data extensions.
Do you have any brilliant ideas to solve this issue?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Erm... Where does "random data extensions" come in? Deleting contacts is something that needs done with caution. You need to plan for how to honour unsubscribes and spam complaints going forward because you're nuking SFMC's ability to save you from yourself. If you have 17m contacts, I guess you know what you're doing? I'd expect you'd also know how to delete 17m contacts, so I'll shut up.

Comment: It is a required requirement. As for the contact deletion I would like clarifications on this issue. The required steps are: pause the synch data sources - contact deletion - resume the synch data sources. Can a contact be resynced from Sales Cloud to Marketing Cloud after deletion from MC?

Comment: I understand that required requirements are required and some required requirements aren't required, they're just desired (for whatever reason). It's up to you to explain what you're doing, so that we can help you. Could you take a step back and explain why you're deleting your contacts, other than it's a required requirement? I don't care too much either way and don't feel like writing a treatise for your benefit.

Comment: The reason is linked to the fact that many contacts are no longer used and the customer has decided to only consider contacts synchronized from salesforce for budgetary reasons.

Comment: OK. So what happens when you mail contacts that have previously unsubscribed or reported your client as a spammer? Could you get your client on the line or do we just need to deal with the required requirement? In short, what you're doing isn't a straight technical question, but has legal implications that I'm not confident you're capable of answering for. Nothing personal.

Comment: @Macca 
I am unable to answer this. The practice should be done next month and for this analysis I am trying to understand how to proceed from people more experienced than me. What could I eliminate? do I only delete the data view bounces and do not follow the requirements of the client who is perhaps ignorant on the subject?

Comment: If the issue is bouncing email addresses and you're only using email as a channel, maybe you have a good reason to do this. Salesforce will be including these contacts in your client's quota. We get it... Salesforce likes money and we're all doing silly things to circumvent. If your client's got a problem with bouncing Leads, deleting them without setting up some suppression of the email addresses you don't like's going to burn their reputation when these things float in again, mailing Leads that have previously unsubscribed's going to burn the reputation and you'll potentially end up in court

Comment: @Macca 
how would you do? To avoid errors and problems how would you proceed with the contact deletion considering that everything is managed by salesforce side and that our MC works with only synchronized salesforce data sources?

Comment: I'd probably reach out for paid advice. I'm likely not be in your region and this isn't a pitch, but deletion of contacts needs working through. Why you're deleting them, how you manage unsubscribes, what's the source of truth... It's typically fairly complicated. Understand that SFMC maintains whether an email address is bouncing, is held or has complained and doesn't tell CRM. Depending on your preference center setup, CRM may or may not be updated and may be updated based on Email or SubscriberKey(Lead or Contact ID). It's one to work through the implications before hitting the nuke.

Comment: @Macca thank you for your time. I will follow your advice and try to investigate better in order not to make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

- If you have all the contacts in a data extension then you can go to
     All contacts > use the delete icon to select the data extensions to
     delete it.

Note - You would need to enable contact deletion before you delete. Also, you can only delete only one million records at a time. So, you can use the below SQL query to segment it by rows. Just change the the row number every time.

```
select x.* from (Select D.Subscriber_Key, D.email_address ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY D.Subscriber_Key) as row 
from [Name of the data extension] as D)x
where x.row > 0 AND x.row <= 1000000
```

Reference - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_delete_contact.htm&type=5

- If you don't have contacts in the data extension then you can raise a
  case to salesforce and they can get you the records in csv file. Post
  that you can import into data extensions from SFTP and delete the
  contact using the data extension
- You can also use the REST API to do the delete.

Reference - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/DeleteByContactKeys.htm

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: With power comes responsibility. @Nap's a nube by the looks of things. Deleting 17m contacts is something that involves answering questions beyond "how do I mess up my account?"... "easy, press the 'mess up my account button'".

Comment: @Macca I am aware and this is the reason why I would like to have clarifications. Deleted contacts will be re-synchronized from salesforce, later.

Comment: @Nap - do keep in mind, that deletion of so many contacts (17 million) will take many weeks! Definitely much longer than you want your sync to be paused. Reason for this is the deletion is a low prio process, running in the background.

Comment: @LukasLunow Assuming we do delete the Contacts, will it be possible for them to resync at a later time? Could there be issues with the Contact data, e.g. because the SC Contact ID would be the same for the deleted and the newly resynchronized Contact in MC?

Comment: @Nap - yes, deleted contacts will be able to re-enter. But their tracking history will be gone, as they will be assigned a new Subscriber ID (still with the same SC Contact ID)

Comment: @LukasLunow thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Get the [Contact Deletion](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_contact_deletion.htm&type=5) enabled first. Reduce the Deletion window to Zero days

Once done, go to Mobile Connect >> Manage Contacts >> Lists

Create a List with any random filter that you like and then set it for deletion.

I'd suggest doing it in manageable chunks (e.g. 1 million at a time)